# Best practice for where to put 2.8k lines of JSON/JS input for knex migration

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I'm writing a knex/objection migration file that adds some non-user generated data to my database. For that, I have to input 2.8k lines of an array of objects:
[image]
It just feels wrong to plop it straight into the migration file, so is there a best/common practice for where I can put this in a JSON file instead and import from there?